group by Nullable field in clickhouse
What I do wrong?
Aggregate by Nullable field "vers_to", looks like strange result of aggregation.
There are 3 rows with null value and 3 rows not null value.
select version();
--24.1.4.20

drop table sc.check_grp_eaist_v_lot;

CREATE TABLE sc.check_grp_eaist_v_lot
(
    vers_date  DateTime,
    id         Decimal(38,6),
    vers_to    Nullable(DateTime)
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PRIMARY KEY (vers_date, id)
ORDER BY (vers_date, id);

insert into sc.check_grp_eaist_v_lot(vers_date,id,vers_to) 
  values(parseDateTime('2024-04-15 03:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),95945837,null),
        (parseDateTime('2024-04-15 03:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),95945945,null),
        (parseDateTime('2024-04-15 03:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),95945950,null)
        (parseDateTime('2024-04-15 03:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),95945836,parseDateTime('2024-04-18 03:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')),
        (parseDateTime('2024-04-15 03:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),95945944,parseDateTime('2024-04-18 03:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')),
        (parseDateTime('2024-04-15 03:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),95945948,parseDateTime('2024-04-18 03:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'));   

select vers_to,sum(1) as cnt
from   sc.check_grp_eaist_v_lot
group by vers_to

vers_to            |cnt|
-------------------|---|
                   |  0|
2024-04-18 05:00:00|  6|

expected result:
vers_to            |cnt|
-------------------|---|
                   |  3|
2024-04-18 05:00:00|  3|


The query is correct. (It is a bit weird to use SUM(1) instead of a mere COUNT(*) for counting, but not wrong.) You should get the expected result. I don't have any idea, why you shouldn't. Maybe the data is not what you think it is? Here is a demo in PostgreSQL, showing that the query is correct: https://dbfiddle.uk/-MyoappA

Changing sum(1) to count(*) don't change output result. And I know that it works in postgres or oracle.

Found https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/61313
Where everything explained.

Okay, so it's a known bug in Clickhouse (den-crane commented on Mar 13: "Broken since 23.12.4.15"). You can probably workaround this by replacing nulls with some default value in your query and converting the default value back to null then.
